exited with code 0 when using simple C# with selenium VS2022
Before attribute it was working fine but as soon I added the attribute the code is not working.
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace ExecuteAutomation
{

    class Program
    {

        //Create the reference for our browser
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
        }

        [SetUp]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            //Navigate to Google Chrome
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
        }


        [Test]
        public void ExecuteTest()
        {
            //Find the element
            IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

            //Perform Ops
            element.SendKeys("ExecuteAutomation");
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }

    }

}

I tried to disable the settings from Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Automatically close console when debugging stops.

Uh, what attribute?

@Flydog57 like [Setup], [Test]

Are you running the program by itself, running it in the debugger (F5 or Debug::Run) or are you running it within a test runner (Test::Debug All Tests)?

After adding NUnit attributes, e.g. [Test], the program no longer acts like a typical console application. You have marked them as tests. You can kick off the tests in several ways using NUit.

The console
From the Test Explorer, right-click on test(s) or categories and choose Run or Debug
From the test itself, <CTRL>+R, T to Run or <CTRL>+R, <CTRL>+T to Debug

See Running Tests in the NUnit docs for more info.
